# If any problem in NP is not in P then NP C ∩ P = ∅

Tags: np-complete, np, polynomial-time-reductions

> If any problem in NP is not in P then NPC ∩ P = ∅

The proof is: *We have $X ∈ NP$ and $X \not\in P$. Assume $Y ∈ NP C ∩ P$. As $X ≤_P Y$ we have $X ∈ P$, which is a contradiction.*

I have not clear the logic step why if there is a polynomial reduction from $X ∈ NP$ to Y, then $X ∈ P$?

Comment: Note: If $NPC \cap P \neq \emptyset$ then $P = NP$.

Comment: sorry. I did not get.

Comment: Remember that $Y$ is in $P$, so there is a polynomial time algorithm to solve it. Thus if $X\leq_P Y$ then you can solve $X$ in polynomial time by reducing it to $Y$ in polynomial time then solving $Y$ in polynomial time.

Comment: Thanks! Now I undestand! please post for points :)